# Workflow for email alerts on subfolders only

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, folder

I've inherited a SharePoint site that includes sub-folders in the document libraries.

When a customer attempts to set an alert on a particular sub-folder, they wind up receiving alert emails for the entire document library. They have requested email workflows as a way around this, but I'm having trouble publishing a workflow that applies only to the sub-folder. The workflows will only publish at the library level.

Is there a way around this?

Even better would be to have a workflow at the site level that allows the email list to be defined whenever it is added to a certain sub-folder so that I can use an email with dynamic text across different libraries/sub-folders.

Answer (score 2):

My support group provided me with the answer to the alerts issue. If you navigate to the folder that contains the sub-folder, click on the sub-folder’s ellipsis, click the ellipsis in the pop-up, and select View Properties…

[image: Subfolder properties screenshot]

…you will get to the properties of the folder. From here you can select Alert Me.

[image: Alert Screenshot]

You can tell you are in the right place because the title of the alert will contain the sub-folder name:

[image: Alert Title screenshot]